# How do I get markdown snippets with Ultisnip to work within math in vim?

Tags: vim, r-markdown, markdown

For example, I have this custom snippet:

```
snippet frac "Fraction"
\frac{${1:numerator}}{${2:denominator}} $0
endsnippet
```

When in math, pressing <tab> does not expand the snippet.

```
$frac <- at this point the dropdown for snippets shows up, but pressing <tab> does nothing.
```

Relevant plugins & Settings:

```
Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc'
Plug 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax'
Plug 'vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown'
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags'

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {}
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-n>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-p>', '<Up>']
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-n>'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = "<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = "<s-tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips", "custom-snippets"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the snippet is not expanded because it is preceded by `$` without any whitespace in between. Try adding `i` to the first line of the snippet:

```
snippet frac "Fraction" i
\frac{${1:numerator}}{${2:denominator}} $0
endsnippet
```

Relevant: `:help UltiSnips-snippet-options`

```
   i   In-word expansion - By default a snippet is expanded only if the tab
       trigger is the first word on the line or is preceded by one or more
       whitespace characters. A snippet with this option is expanded
       regardless of the preceding character. In other words, the snippet can
       be triggered in the middle of a word.
```